# Remote machine: Your terminal lacks the ability to clear the screen or position the cursor

Tags: ssh, remote

Linux Mint 18.1 (64 bit) Xfce, Emacs 25.3

If I want to connect(via ssh) to remote Linux macnine I do next step:

1. Open terminal
2. ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no mylogin@192.xxx.xxx.16

As result I success connect to remote machine.
In remote machine I start Midnight Commander by mc. And it's start success.
Nice.

So I want to do same steps by Emacs 25.3

My steps:

1. M-x shell
2. ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no mylogin@192.xxx.xxx.16

As result I success connect to remote machine.
But when I try to start Midnight Commander by mc I get error:

```
Your terminal lacks the ability to clear the screen or position the cursor.
```

Comment: Note that `M-x shell` provides only a "dumb terminal", whereas `M-x term` is a very capable terminal emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Use `M-x term` instead of `M-x shell`.  `shell` isn't a terminal emulator, `term` is.  Also a hint: `term-mode` has two submodes, `line-mode` and `char-mode`.  You can switch between them with `C-c C-k` and `C-c C-j`.  `line-mode` is more like a normal Emacs buffer, e.g. you don't have a lot of Emacs key bindings like `M-x` in `char-mode`.

Comment: I try open terminal by M-x term.
I try two mode: line-mode and char-mode.
I success connect to remote Unix machine.
By when I try to start Midnight Commadner (mc) I get error:

Unknown terminal: eterm-color
Check the TERM environment variable.
Also make sure that the terminal is defined in the terminfo database.
Alternatively, set the TERMCAP environment variable to the desired
termcap entry.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083177/eterm-color-unknown-terminal-type

Comment: Or if it's easier, install Emacs on the remote machine, that should add the `eterm-color` termcap entry.

Answer (score 0):

Use Tramp. Open in your local Emacs `C-x C-f /ssh:mylogin@192.xxx.xxx.16:`

Comment: Success connect to remote machine by Tramp mode. OK. How start Midnigt Commander?

Comment: Well, don't know whether Midnight Commander could / should be started inside Emacs. You have dired, which gives you already some of its features. And on the EmacsWiki, some other packages are mentioned, like mc.el https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MidnightCommanderMode and sunrise-commander.el https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Sunrise_Commander - I haven't tried them yet.